# My normal map isn't coming out right on my mesh

Tags: modeling, normal-map

I'm following Blender Guru's tutorial on the anvil, and I'm stumped.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/j70j2.jpg

As you can see, the normal map just isn't coming out right.  It looks like a flat image on the mesh.  I followed everything to a T, I'm not sure what could be wrong. 
  Possibly my mesh?  Also, I noticed my anvil is a lot less... "metallic" looking than his if that's the right word.  Even though our settings for the material are the same, mine feels like its made out of clay still.  If anybody could help in either regard, that would be amazing.

File: [image]

Comment: hard to say, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Ah, didn't know you could do that.  Cool!  I uploaded the file, but I had to delete the sculpted anvil because it took too much space: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6535" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6535/)

Comment: I figured it out!  It turns out I needed to set the empty section beneath 'tangent space' in my normal converter node to 'UV map'.  I'm unsure as to why I needed to do that, and the tutorial didn't, but I'm just happy it works.